# Multiple replacements within the same variable

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a string that looks like this:

```
mylist = `<div>some stuff</div>A lot of code in between<span>more stuff</span>`;
```

I want to replace `some stuff` with `things` and `more stuff` with `many things` so I do this:

```
 mylist = mylist.replace(`some stuff`, 'things');
 mylist = mylist.replace(`more stuff`, 'many things');
```

It works but I'm sure there must be a much better approach. What should it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain the `replace` calls:

```js
mylist = mylist.replace(`some stuff`, 'things').replace(`more stuff`, 'many things');
```

If you want to store the pairs in an object for scalability, you can loop through the object's entries (with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)) and replace all occurences of each key with its value:

```js
const obj = {
  "some stuff": "things",
  "more stuff": "many things"
}

var str = "<div>some stuff</div>A lot of code in between<span>more stuff</span>"

Object.entries(obj).forEach((k,v) => str = str.replace(k,v))

console.log(str)
```

Comment: your first answer looks more straightforward to me. Is there any disadvantage that might discourages a coder like security issues when compared to the second one?

Comment: @CainNuke there's no security issues with the first solution. The second solution simply makes it more scalable as its much more easier to change what you want to replace.

Answer (score 2):

You can first create a `changes` object which contain `key-value` of `replace-replacement` and then iterate over the `key-value` and replace the `key` with the `value`

This is better because if you have multiple replacements then It will work every time if you just add more `replacer - replacement` in the object itself.

You don't have to add extra `replace` statement, just add `key-value` in the `changes` and you are good to go.

```js
let mylist = `<div>some stuff</div>A lot of code in between<span>more stuff</span>`;

const changes = {
  "some stuff": "things",
  "more stuff": "many things",
};

mylist = Object.entries(changes).reduce((str, [k, v]) => str.replace(k, v), mylist);
console.log(mylist)
```